# Strikethrough in cell using itext in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, itext, cell

I have two numbers one above the other, but the first one must have an Strikethrough, I'm using a table and cell to put both numbers in the table, is there a way to make what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding an extra answer for the sake of completeness.

Please take a look at the [SimpleTable6](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable6) example:

[image]

In the first row, we strike through a number using a `STRIKETHRU` font as explained by Paulo:

```
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, Font.STRIKETHRU);
table.addCell(new Phrase("0123456789", font));
```

In this case, iText has made a couple of decisions for you: where do I put the line? How thick is the line?

If you want to make these decisions yourself, you can use the `setUnderline()` method:

```
chunk1.setUnderline(1.5f, -1);
table.addCell(new Phrase(chunk1));
Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk("0123456789");
chunk2.setUnderline(1.5f, 3.5f);
table.addCell(new Phrase(chunk2));
```

If you pass a negative value for the y-offset parameter, the `Chunk` will be underlined (see first column). You can also use this method to strike through text by passing a positive y-offset.

As you can see, we also defined the thickness of the line (`1.5f`). There is another `setUnderline()` method that also allows you to pass the following parameters:

- *color* - the color of the line or null to follow the text color
- *thickness* - the absolute thickness of the line
- *thicknessMul* - the thickness multiplication factor with the font size
- *yPosition* - the absolute y position relative to the baseline
- *yPositionMul* - the position multiplication factor with the font size
- *cap* - the end line cap. Allowed values are P`dfContentByte.LINE_CAP_BUTT`, `PdfContentByte.LINE_CAP_ROUND` and `PdfContentByte.LINE_CAP_PROJECTING_SQUARE`

See http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html

Comment: Thanks for the example, both answers, yours and Paulo are the thing that I was looking for, thank you very much to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a font with the style STRIKETHRU.

```
Font f = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.STRIKETHRU);
```

Comment: in my case, Cell setFont method takes PDfont and not Font. I am not seeing any option in PDFont to add strikethru