# IText Stamper undeline specific text

Tags: java, itext, underline, pdfstamper

I'm trying to do a report from a java swing application, I tried jasper reports and other tools, but I don't understand how to use them properly.

I gave a try to itext, and I actually have something like this.

```
   public void createPDF(){

        try {

             PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("pdf/watermark.pdf"); // input PDF
             PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\FIREFENIX\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Java\\PDFCreator\\src\\pdf\\watermarkFinal.pdf")); // output PDF

             BaseFont bfArialPlain = BaseFont.createFont("/font/arial.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
             BaseFont bfArialBold = BaseFont.createFont("/font/arialbd.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
             BaseFont bfArialBlack = BaseFont.createFont("/font/ariblk.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

             for (int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){

                  PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(i);

                  //TOP LEFT
                  over.beginText();
                  over.setFontAndSize(bfArialBold, 9);
                  over.setTextMatrix(040, 670);
                  over.showText("Registry Date: ");   //<-----That field/line/text
                  over.endText();

                  over.beginText();
                  over.setFontAndSize(bfArialPlain, 9);
                  over.setTextMatrix(115, 670);
                  over.showText("21/07/2016");
                  over.endText();

                  over.beginText();
                  over.setFontAndSize(bfArialBold, 9);
                  over.setTextMatrix(040, 660);
                  over.showText("Validation Date: ");  //<-----And that one
                  over.endText();

                  over.beginText();
                  over.setFontAndSize(bfArialPlain, 9);
                  over.setTextMatrix(115, 660);
                  over.showText("21/07/2016");
                  over.endText();

                  //TOP RIGHT...
                  //...
                  //...



            }

            File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\FIREFENIX\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Java\\PDFCreator\\src\\pdf\\watermarkFinal.pdf");
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            //////////PRINT DISABLED////////Desktop.getDesktop().print(myFile);

            stamper.close();

            reader.close(); 


           } catch (IOException | DocumentException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(PDFCreator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }

  }
```

I need to have thoose 2 lines underlined.

How can I do it?

There is any other way I can do this easyer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the very difficult way to add content. There's a much easier way as explained in the official documentation: [How to add text at an absolute position on the top of the first page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-absolute-position-top-first-page)

Instead of:

```
cb.BeginText();
cb.MoveText(700, 30);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
cb.ShowText("My status");
cb.EndText();
```

Use:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(i));
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(30, 600, 523, 720));
ct.addElement(new Paragraph("My status"));
ct.go();
```

If you want to underline text, you need to use a `Chunk` as is done in this FAQ entry: [Strikethrough in cell using itext in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617095)

So let's adapt the previous snippet:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(i));
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(30, 600, 523, 720));
Chunk c = new Chunk("Underlined text");
c.setUnderline(1.5f, -1);
ct.addElement(new Paragraph(c));
ct.go();
```

For more info, see [Absolute positioning of text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text) and the search results for [underline](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-search?keys=underline&field_itext_version_tid%5B%5D=909).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I also had a library conflict between itext 5 and itext 7, this doesn't work on v7 and v5, but I downloaded the 5.5 and works perfectly.

Comment: I answered with iText 5 code, because you presented iText 5 code: `PdfStamper` no longer exists in iText 7. If you want the iText 7 answer, please post it as a new question

Comment: @JesúsSuárezBorrell, the conflict is because 5 and 7 are not backwards compatible. itext 7 is a from the ground up rewrite of the functionality in iText5.